# How can I combine *\u" and the UTF-8 code for console output? (Java)

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

I would like to combine a `"\u"` with a `String` that contains a Hex-Code so that I can print out a unicode character in the console.

I've tried something like this, but the console only prints regular text, eg `\uf600`:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
emoji.codePoints()
    .mapToObj(Integer::toHexString)
    .forEach((n) -> arr.add(n));  // arr will contain hex strings

for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i += 2) {
     System.out.println("\\u" + arr.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Can you change your code to just add some strings to your array? It's a little difficult to run this code as is.

Comment: "emoji" is a String that only contains the emoji “‍‍‍”. Hex-Value: 1F469 200D 1F4BB

Comment: I meant for your code example in your Question. I do not have an "emoji" object, that your code relies on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, `\u` exists only in the compiler, as a convenience to help you add unicode character literals in your source code. If at run time you create a string that contains \ u followed by hex digits, there is no mechanism in place to transform it into a single `char`.

It sounds like you want to transform each code point separately to a string. Here is one way you can do that: use `Character.toChars` to transform the code point to a char array, and then build a new string from the char array:

```
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
emoji.codePoints().mapToObj(Character::toChars).map(String::new)
    .forEach(arr::add)
```